# Headless safari browse via windows

Tags: selenium, safari, headless

Can I run headless safari browser via windows?
I did not tried it yet but it's just I wanted to check if it's possible. If anyone have what all I need.

Comment: As I know, Safari for Windows doesn‘t exist anymore.

Comment: Yeah! I know that but what about running it through headless. If I don't have Chrome on my system I can still run it using headless via phontom.js or htmlunitdriver.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is no. The reason for this is an issue with Safari specifically, not Selenium. You can find an explanation on this relevant GitHub issue opened under the Selenium repo: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5985

The GitHub issue is marked as closed by the Selenium developers, because Safari application itself does not support headless mode.

Comment: Feel free to mark this post as accepted answer to your question so other users with similar issue can see it was helpful for you.